# Procedurally generating large list of values in Haskell -- most idiomatic approach? memory management?

Tags: haskell, idioms

I have a function that takes a series of random numbers/floats, and uses them to generate a value/structure (ie, taking a random velocity and position of the point a ball is thrown from and outputting the coordinates of where it would land).  And I need to generate several thousands in succession.

The way I have everything implemented is each calculation takes in an stdGen, uses it to generate several numbers, and passes out a new stdGen to allow it to be chained to another one.

And to do this for 10000 items, I make a sort of list from `generate_item n` which basically outputs a `(value,gen)` tuple (the value being the value i'm trying to calculate), where the value of `gen` is the recursively outputted stdGen from the calculations involved in getting the value from `generate_item n-1`

However, this program seems to crawl to be impractically slow at around a thousand results or so.  And seems to definitely not be scalable.  Could it have to do with the fact that I am storing all of the `generate_item` results in memory?

Or is there a more idomatic way of approaching this problem in Haskell using Monads or something than what I have describe above?

Note that the code to generate the algorithm from the random value generates 10k within seconds even in high-level scripting languages like ruby and python; these calculations are hardly intensive.

Code

```
-- helper functions that take in StdGen and return (Result,new StdGen)
plum_radius :: StdGen -> (Float,StdGen)
unitpoint   :: Float -> StdGen -> ((Float,Float,Float),StdGen)
plum_speed  :: Float -> StdGen -> (Float,StdGen)

-- The overall calculation of the value
plum_point  :: StdGen -> (((Float,Float,Float),(Float,Float,Float)),StdGen)
plum_point gen  = (((px,py,pz),(vx,vy,vz)),gen_out)
  where
    (r, gen2)         = plum_radius gen
    ((px,py,pz),gen3) = unitpoint r gen2
    (s, gen4)         = plum_speed r gen3
    ((vx,vy,vz),gen5) = unitpoint s gen4
    gen_out           = gen5

-- Turning it into some kind of list
plum_data_list  :: StdGen -> Int -> (((Float,Float,Float),(Float,Float,Float)),StdGen)
plum_data_list seed_gen 0  = plum_point seed_gen
plum_data_list seed_gen i  = plum_point gen2
  where
    (_,gen2)  = plum_data_list seed_gen (i-1)

-- Getting 100 results
main = do
  gen <- getStdGen
  let data_list = map (plum_data_list gen) [1..100]
  putStrLn List.intercalate " " (map show data_list)
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code you are working with, it is usually easier to understand and help with a concreate example to work with.

Comment: Added in code; hope it helps!

Comment: What the heck is up with `plum_data_list` which generates a bunch of points and throws all of them away but the first one?  That's probably not what you intended -- see my answer for how to write a function that generates a list of random things.

Comment: @luqui well, the items in `plum_data_list` are accessed sequentially so I guess I sort of naively assumed that they were cached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other posters have good points, `StdGen` doesn't perform very well, and you should probably try to use State instead of manually passing the generator along. But I think the biggest problem is your `plum_data_list` function.

It seems to be intended to be some kind of lookup, but since it's implemented recursively without any memoization, the calls you make have to recurse to the base case. That is, `plum_data_list seed_gen 100` needs the random generator from `plum_data_list seed_gen 99` and so on, until `plum_data_list seed_gen 0`. This will give you quadratic performance when you try to generate a list of these values.

Probably the more idiomatic way is to let `plum_data_list seed_gen` generate an infinite list of points like so:

```
plum_data_list :: StdGen -> [((Float,Float,Float),(Float,Float,Float))]
plum_data_list seed_gen = first_point : plum_data_list seed_gen'
  where
    (first_point, seed_gen') = plum_point seed_gen
```

Then you just need to modify the code in `main` to something like `take 100 $ plum_data_list gen`, and you are back to linear performance.

Comment: I think you found the main memory drain source :)

Answer (score 6):

Consider just using the mersenne-twister and the [vector-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-random/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector-Random-Mersenne.html) package , which is specifically optimized to generate large amounts of high-quality random data.

Lists are unsuitable for allocating large amounts of data -- better to use a packed representation -- unless you're streaming.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the pattern you are describing -- taking an `StdGen` and then returning a tuple with a value and another `StdGen` to be chained into the next computation -- is *exactly* the pattern the [`State`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) monad encodes.  Refactoring your code to use it might be a good way to start to become familiar with monadic patterns.

As for your performance problem, `StdGen` is notoriously slow.  I haven't done a lot with this stuff, but I've heard [mersenne twister](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64) is faster.

However, you might also want to post your code, since in cases where you are generating large lists, laziness can really work to your advantage or disadvantage depending on how you are doing it.  But it is hard to give specific advice without seeing what you are doing.  One rule of thumb just in case you are coming from another functional language such as Lisp -- when generating a list (or other lazy data structure -- e.g. a tree, but not a `Int`), **avoid** tail recursion.  The intuition for it being faster does not transfer to lazy languages.  E.g. use (written without the monadic style that I would acutally use in practice)

```
randoms :: Int -> StdGen -> (StdGen, [Int])
randoms 0 g = (g, [])
randoms n g = let (g',  x)  = next g
                  (g'', xs) = randoms (n-1) g'
              in (g'', x : xs)
```

This will allow the result list to be "streamed", so you can access the earlier parts of it before generating the later parts.  (In this state case, it's a little subtle because accessing the resulting `StdGen` will have to generate the whole list, so you'll have to carefully avoid doing that until after you have consumed the list -- I wish there was a fast random generator that supported a good `split` operation, then you could get around having to return a generator at all).

Oh, just in case you're having trouble getting going with the monads thing, here's the above function written with a state monad:

```
randomsM :: Int -> State StdGen [Int]
randomsM 0 = return []
randomsM n = do
    x <- state next
    xs <- randomsM (n-1)
    return (x : xs)
```

See the correspondence?

Comment: Also, `randomsM = flip replicateM (state next)`.

Comment: Note that all these patterns are captured in the mersenne-twister packages.